# Duplicate Results below Collapsed Dimension Hierarchy

Tags: excel, pivot, ssas

We are retrieving Data from an SSAS Cube to analyse Stock-Purchases and use the default Pivots in MS-Excel to display the results.

Both the Fact-Table, and the Fact-Dimension (Measure-Group) contains references to both the Time-Dimension and the Assortment-Dimension via their respective Keys.
The Assortment Dimension does not feature Hierarchies and consists solely of the Assortment itself.

[image: Assortment-Dimension]

The Time-Dimension features Hierarchies for both, Calendar- and Fiscal-Year.[image: Time-Dimension]

When I select Attributes from both Dimensions as Rows in the Excel-Pivot (first Fiscal-Quarters, then Assortment), I see the expected result of collapsable Fact-Table entries grouped by Fiscal-Quarters and Assortment.

[image: Expected Result]

However, when I select a Hierarchy from my Time-Dimension, aswell as the Assortment, I get the following unexpected result:
The Assortment-Dimension is correctly grouped within each Time-Hierarchy, however **when the Date-Hierarchy is collapsed, the Members of the Assortment are shown *below*, instead of within the group**.

[image]

Once I expand the first order of the hierarchy, members below the hierarchy-level disappear, but reappear for every child-member of this hierarchy.
The (grand- and sub-) totals of Measures are correctly calculated, including calculated-members, but are shown, even when the above-mentioned member is collapsed.

My expectated behavior is, that members of the corresponding dimension are only shown within the grouping sets of their specific hierarchy-level and hidden, when it is collapsed.

How can I achieve this?